# what is the exact meaning of ナメの画 in below sentence?

Tags: particle-から

the complete sentence is: "こっちから  ナメの画…   。"
I know that the whole meaning is: "film him from this side, too!" but I don't know the exact meaning of "ナメの画" in the aforesaid sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it's a jargon for camera work.

From [here](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1043065455), なめる means

> 「なめる」は、手前にあるものを半分ないしは４分の１くらい映して、奥のにあるものを撮影する技法ですね。
>
> It is a way to shoot an object on the far side (from the shooter's perspective) with objects on the near side being partially (25-50%) in the picture.

> 「左に女の子の後ろ姿をなめて、奥にいる女の子の好きな男の子をとる。」といった感じでしょうか。

In this example 手前=the girl and 奥=the boy, the camera shoots the boy from behind the girl, and the girl's back is partially in the picture.

Comment: Thank you very much